# Open vstfs url from running instance of Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017, tfs-code-review

This should be simple, right? I copied a link such as `vstfs:///CodeReview/Request/37229?url=http. . . . .` (code review) and tried to open it in running Visual Studio 2017. The closest I came with is *View-Other Windows-Web Browser*. Pasted my link, pressed enter, and same dialog *"How do you want to open this?"* appeared as if I was opening it from File Explorer. I thought, if would open it in the same VS. If I click OK in the dialog, it opens the new instance of VS and opens this review in Team Explorer. Is there a way to open this link in running VS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Open vstfs url from running instance of Visual Studio

Sorry for any inconvenience.

I am afraid there is no such way we could open vstfs url in existing Visual Studio instance.

There is a user voice about it (*Since the old visual studio uservoice forum is deactivated, I could not post the link here.* )

[image]

If it is important to you, you can open a [new ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=8) here:

[image]

You can vote and add your comments for this feedback. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the info. I am just not sure, why would I post it under Azure Dev Ops? This is just plain VS issue on my side. We get TFS email about code review and it sends 2 links  - 1 for web portal and 1 vstfs. I just like to use VS as review tool. This is not a show stopper but would be nice if Team Explorer had such feature to open VSTFS link

Comment: @T.S., yes, you are right. This should be Visual Studio feature request. Sorry for that. Updated the answer.